# comparing a variable amount of nested lists

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

I'm trying to make a simple k-means but where you can choose the number of clusters and i've figured out how to get the distance between each center but from here i need to compare all the values between one point and all the other centroids to assign each point to a centroid. So basically i need to compare a variable amount of list values to a variable amount of centroids in order to label them. But how do i compare variable amount values in a variable amount of nested lists in order so i can label them to centroids?

```
data = genfromtxt('datafiler/data.csv', delimiter=',')

Centroids = np.array([[30, 70], [70, 30], [50, 50], [70, 70]])
k = input("Number of clusters:")

distList = []
    for x in range(int(k)):
        distList.append([])

    for v in range(int(k)):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            dist = np.linalg.norm(Centroids[v]-data[i])
            distList[v].append(dist)
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: I edited the post so it might be more clear

Comment: Just use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html